# php delete only partial contents from a log file

Tags: php, file, logging

In my recent application, i had to write a series of cronjobs and i use to log them to a custom log file, these log files contains details of exceptions and/or shows the status of each execution.

Problem is my log file is getting bulkier and i would like to clear some of the contents from the file and keep it slim.
Like say only keep last 10 days contents inside this file and clear the older contents.

My sample error log file is given below:

```
[2019-05-16 06:38:16 AM]: Catalog Import - Process started.
[2019-05-16 06:38:17 AM]: - Brands processed.
[2019-05-16 06:38:18 AM]: - Categories processed.
[2019-05-16 06:38:27 AM]: - Catalogues processed.
[2019-05-16 06:38:29 AM]: - CSV generated.
[2019-05-16 06:38:29 AM]: Catalog Import - Process completed.
[2019-05-16 06:38:29 AM]: =======================================================================
[2019-05-17 06:38:16 AM]: Catalog Import - Process started.
[2019-05-17 06:38:17 AM]: Exception - (json encoded response usually array stuffs)
[2019-05-17 06:38:18 AM]: - Categories processed.
[2019-05-17 06:38:27 AM]: - Catalogues processed.
[2019-05-17 06:38:29 AM]: Error - (json encoded response usually array stuffs)
[2019-05-17 06:38:29 AM]: Catalog Import - Process completed.
[2019-05-17 06:38:29 AM]: =======================================================================
```

What would be the best way to delete the contents periodically in the log file?

Comment: Rotate log files on a daily basis, instead of trying to edit one. Then you can simply delete old log files.

Comment: Or if above is not good for you, loop the file line by line and read the date and do what needs to be done based on the date.

Comment: @RolandWeber: Nope that is not an option i don't want to keep multiple log files....I just want to clear the single log file periodically.

Comment: @Andreas: I like your idea but am not much of a coding guy...can you help me with sample codes on this....to make it more easy just delete first n lines from this log file, if the log file size reaches certain limit say 5MB.

Comment: That is harder to do that removing the lines with old date. I can write up a quick answer on your request in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file and loop the file.
When you find a date that is "too old" delete the line.

Then save the new data in the log file.

```
$log_file = 'catalog_import.log';
// get the file contents as array.
$lines = file( $log_file);
if (!empty($lines)) {
    foreach ($lines as $row => $line) {
        // if older than 10 days.
        if (time() - strtotime(substr($line, 1, 10)) > 60 * 60 * 24 * 10) {
            unset($lines[$row]);
        }
    }
}
//write the filtered data to the file.
file_put_contents($log_file, implode("", $lines));

die('logs cleared successfully.');
```

Please do this on a copy first as it's untested code.

Comment: ...and make sure that the log file is not written to while it's being processed in this fashion.

Comment: @Andreas: your code did the trick with some minor changes....i have updated it please check it.

Comment: Guyz i have still some doubts about its performance...what if my log file is too big say 1GB and i need to clear some of the data in it and keep the rest will the array method be sufficient.

Comment: Try it. I don't know. But if you clear it daily then it shouldn't grow that big. Right?

Comment: @Andreas: yup that would only work for new log files on which i implement this cleaning code, But the problem is i already have may big log files which i need to deal with. I will try some tests on this and will let you know.

Comment: I don't think it will be more than a few seconds of processing time even with a 1 GB file. Once you have removed the excess once the file will be small and it will be faster the next time.

Comment: If you need to process huge files, you shouldn't load them into memory in one go. Open input file and a differently named output file at the same time, then read one batch of data from the input file, and write whatever passes the filter to the output file. And make sure to user a buffered stream for the output.